# WordPress is adding pagination for all pages not only for blog page, How to remove pagination for all pages except blog/posts page?

Tags: functions, theme-development, url-rewriting, pagination, htaccess

You know WordPress is adding pagination for all pages not only for posts page/blog page.
For example [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), I'm getting URLs like [www.mysite.com/page/15](http://www.mysite.com/page/15), etc.
Here, [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) has a static home page. Why I'm getting these types of URLs? Is there any solution to this?